# Average of each two columns in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, mean

I have an array as follows:

```
arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4];
```

How can I get the average of each two columns, so that the result is:

```
ans=[2.5 4.5 6.5 8.5 ...];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using convolution?

```
arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4];

arr2=[1 1];

A=conv(arr,arr2)/2;

mean2=A(2:2:end-1)

plot(mean2)
```

If your array number is not always even, and you want to add final element at the end  of the result array when array number is odd,

```
arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 6];

arr2=[1 1];

A=conv(arr,arr2)/2;

if mod(length(arr),2) == 1;

   mean2=[A(2:2:end-1) arr(end)]

else 
   mean2=[A(2:2:end-1)]
end

plot(mean2)
```

Comment: how can I take the last element in case I have one extra number in the array, for example: arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 6]; so that mean2=2.5000    4.5000    6.5000    8.5000    1.5000    3.5000   6];

Comment: I think if you want to add your final element at the end of result array when  array is odd, you could make a decision with if statement.

Answer (score 3):

Convert it into a two-row matrix using [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html), and divide-by-2:

```
>> arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4];
>> arrbar = sum(reshape(arr,2,[]))/2

arrbar =

    2.5000    4.5000    6.5000    8.5000    1.5000    3.5000
```

---

Augmenting the solution per your comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40209075/3121310), we can guard against odd lengths with a little indexing trick:

```
>> arrbar = sum(reshape([arr,arr(end:end-(mod(end,2)==0))],2,[]))/2
arrbar =
    2.5000    4.5000    6.5000    8.5000    1.5000    3.5000

>> arr=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 6];
>> arrbar = sum(reshape([arr,arr(end:end-(mod(end,2)==0))],2,[]))/2
arrbar =
    2.5000    4.5000    6.5000    8.5000    1.5000    3.5000    6.0000
```

The extra indexing appends the final element for odd lengths so the final average is simply the final element.